# Multiple constraints on Set/Array

Tags: arrays, swift, set, swift-protocols

Put shortly: How does one put a protocol constraint on a `Set` or an `Array` in Swift?

It is known that you can't make a `Set` consisting of a protocol type because a protocol by itself can't be made to adhere to the `Hashable` method.

However, if all classes adopting a certain protocol also inherit from a base class such as `NSObject`, it should be possible to make a `Set` consisting of several classes adhering to said protocol because of `NSObject` adopting the prerequisite `Hashable` protocol.

Nonetheless, I can't even find out how to make a plain `Array` with a base class and protocol constraint.

Adding a generic constraint such as

`let array:Array<T: NSObject where T: NSObjectProtocol>`
only results in `Expected '>' to complete generic argument list`.

`let set = Set<NSObject:NSObjectProtocol>()`
results in the same error as well as `Expected expression`.

`let set = Set<NSObject, NSObjectProtocol>()`
results in `Generic type 'Set' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1)`.

Comment: It's currently not possible to directly express a type that inherits from a class and adopts a given protocol – but [it will be in a future version of the language](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) :)

Comment: I'd accept that as an answer.